# Flatpickr - Limit the amount of dates that can be selected

Tags: jquery, datepicker, flatpickr

I am using 'flatpickr' as a datetime picker on my app. This date picker allows for multiple dates to be selected but after reading the docs I can't find any way to limit the maximum amount of selected dates.

Jquery:

```
$('#gig_date_multi').flatpickr({
  "mode": "multiple",
  "locale": "<%= I18n.locale %>",
  minDate: new Date(),
  enableTime: true,
  time_24hr: true,
  minuteIncrement: 15,

    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {

      var array = selectedDates;
      if (array.length >= 3) {
        console.log("YOU HAVE REACHED YOUR LIMIT")
      } else {
        console.log("YOU CAN STILL SELECT MORE DATES")
      }

      var newHTML = [];
      $.each(array, function(index, value) {
        var formatted = moment(value).format("HH:mm - dddd Do MMMM YYYY");
        newHTML.push('<span>' + formatted + '</span>');
      });

      $(".multi-dates").html(newHTML.join(""));

    }
});
```

Here when 3 dates are selected the console outputs "YOU HAVE REACHED YOUR LIMIT" and I was thinking maybe I could disable all dates (apart from previously selected ones) when this occurs.

Flatpickr has a `disable` and `enable` function but I am unsure how I can integrate this into the code... I am a jquery beginner.

The docs show these two methods;

```
{
    "disable": [
        function(date) {
            // return true to disable
            return (date.getDay() === 5 || date.getDay() === 6);

        }
    ],
    "locale": {
        "firstDayOfWeek": 1 // start week on Monday
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    enable: ["2017-03-30", "2017-05-21", "2017-06-08", new Date(2017, 8, 9) ]
}
```

Comment: Are these a range of dates  or individual dates that can be selected?

Comment: @Cue These are individual dates that can be selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

> [set(option, value)](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/instance-methods-properties-elements/#methods): Sets a config option optionto value, redrawing the calendar and updating the current view, if necessary

In order to disable all dates except the 3 selected you can write:

```
instance.set('enable', selectedDates);
```

and, in order to reset you can:

```
instance.set('enable', []);
```

A different approach can be based on [Enabling dates by a function](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/examples/#disabling-all-dates-except-select-few):

```
instance.set('enable', [function(date) {
    if (selectedDates.length >= 3) {
        var currDateStr = FlatpickrInstance.prototype.formatDate(date, "d/m/Y")
        var x = selectedDatesStr.indexOf(currDateStr);
        return x != -1;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}]);
```

The snippet:

```js
$('#gig_date_multi').flatpickr({
    "mode": "multiple",
    "locale": 'en',
    minDate: new Date(),
    enableTime: true,
    time_24hr: true,
    minuteIncrement: 15,
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
        var selectedDatesStr = selectedDates.reduce(function(acc, ele) {
            var str = instance.formatDate(ele, "d/m/Y");
            acc = (acc == '') ? str : acc + ';' + str;
            return acc;
        }, '');
        instance.set('enable', [function(date) {
            if (selectedDates.length >= 3) {
                var currDateStr = instance.formatDate(date, "d/m/Y")
                var x = selectedDatesStr.indexOf(currDateStr);
                return x != -1;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }]);
    }
});
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flatpickr"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="gig_date_multi">
```

Comment: While this seems to be almost working, there does appear to be a bug with the code. If I select 3 dates, then deselect one, all the times change to 00:00.

Comment: @RobHughes You are right. Sorry for the delay. Snippet updated. Let me know. Thanks

Comment: Many thanks for this, this does work now. The 'enable' or 'disable' functions appeared to remove all time data. I had previously changed the code to hide and show dates using css selectors which seemed to work ok, but I prefer your code, although I don't understand all of it.

Comment: @RobHughes Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

On a side note, if anyone wants to disable past date as well as ***time*** selection in Flatpickr, use `Date().getTime()` like this:

```
 $("input.picker-datetime").flatpickr({
        enableTime: true,
        dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
        time_24hr: true,
        minDate: new Date().getTime()
    });
```